# How hard would it be to port Amiga OS4 to x86 or ARM?

Tags: amiga, programming, operating-system

This question was raised on Facebook a few hours ago. Some say it's possible, others say impossible. What do you experts say?

Comment: AmigaOS 4 only runs on PowerPC CPUs, but was largely based on AmigaOS 3.1 source code which only ran on 68k CPUs. So the code base has already been ported from one architecture to another. The difficulties in porting would probably come from endian issues and the almost complete lack of any Amiga-compatible hardware devices on any existing computers using x86 and ARM CPUs. However regardless of the difficulties it would be possible, just unlikely that anyone would consider it practical. In any case, I'm not sure if this question is on-topic here.

Comment: Since an x86 (or ARM) machien is turing complete, every port from any other machine is possible. Isn't it? as @RossRidge already mentioned, the question in't on topic, nor does it make much sense, or useful. I also see no way to make it more specific to be answered beside above platitude.

Comment: Would the expert opinion "quite hard, but not excessively hard" be acceptable? Even though I don't think that the question is off-topic, it is unclear what you're asking, and the answers would be opinion based.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to modify a PowerPC emulator to the specifics of the Amiga hardware. There is e.g. PearPC http://pearpc.sourceforge.net/

Comment: QEMU is probably the best approach, to build an emulator.

Comment: @Raffzahn, Turing-completeness is only a statement about the mathematical capabilities of a computer.  Real-world computers do a range of things (such as I/O) that fall completely outside the scope of Turing-completeness.

Comment: @Mark Interesting. So you mean there are like I/O operations that would prohibit the **port** of AmigaOS to a modern PC? Mind to name one?

Comment: @Raffzahn, it's not necessarily I/O.  If I'm reading the description of the "RAD Disk" functionality right, it wouldn't be portable to all x86 hardware: some x86 BIOSs perform a memory self-test as part of a warm boot, which would result in the ramdisk's contents being wiped.

Comment: @Raffzahn, going the other direction, you can't port Linux to an Amiga 1000, no matter how much RAM you stuff into it: the A1000 lacks a MMU, which Linux relies on for its memory management.

Comment: @Mark Here's a real port of Linux running on an 8-bit microcontroller without a hardware MMU: https://hackaday.com/2012/03/28/building-the-worst-linux-pc-ever/

Comment: @Mark So what? Then the RAD Disk wouldn't be possible on **some** x86 hardware. Not an argument against a port in general.  Beside, a memory test not necersarry destroy RAM content, *some* BIOS also allow to skip that test. It's rather rare that porting an OS to some different/New Hardware goes without some caveats. Having droped out of Linux 68k already in the early days, I still remember several rather subtile user land differences where wrapers where needed. Still it was Linux.

Comment: @Mark While it wasn't about porting Lnux to a non MMU machine, this has been done more than one time. As with every port to new hardware, some dunctions might not work the same way, still they work. Everything, from shared memory to shared libraries can work in a real mode address space. All that's missing is protection agains not well behaving programs or false asumptions. While having an MMU was a core idea for Linux, a port can live without. After all, we're back to the turing complete part, arn't we :))

Comment: @Raffzahn: still, it must be said that in non-MMU Linux fork() doesn't really work (vfork() should be used instead, where possible), and mmap() works differently: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/nommu-mmap.txt. Also, memory is heavily fragmented, programs should avoid random allocation patterns, large allocations, large stacks, ...

Comment: @ninjalj There are always differences. And when going toward a machines limitations, one always need to look close. No matter if a MMU is involves or not. Just try to run some modern software on a 32 MiB 486. An OS may (and should) hide hardware details to a great extend, still, programmers should be aware about the works even before going toward the limits. Just because todays machiens are almost identical wherever you go and grossly overprovisioned, doesn't mean that lazyness is a feat.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[AROS](http://aros.sourceforge.net/) is an existing reimplementation of AmigaOS 3.1 with cross-platform compatibility (current distributions run on MC68020, PPC and x86 platforms; given the diversity of these platforms I would presume adding ARM compatibility would be fairly simple).  While its developers have stated they have no desire to implement the updates that were included in the more recent AmigaOS 4 release, it would serve as a useful base for a fork.

Wikipedia has a [list of the most major changes in AmigaOS 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AmigaOS_4#AmigaOS_4_prominent_features).  There's nothing here that's Earth-shatteringly difficult.  As OS development tasks go, it's not trivially easy but it isn't really hard either.  Of course, working on an OS is never quite as simple as working on standard applications, as you have to either deal with emulated hardware or running on a system that may not have a functioning OS while you test it.  I reckon a small team with people with experience in the relevant fields (low level hardware interfacing, on-disk data structures, UI and graphics development) could do it in about a year.  So from a technical perspective, I'd say it's clearly achievable.

But then, the AmigaOne platform and consequently AmigaOS 4 were commercial failures, so the need for such a system doesn't seem to be there otherwise it wouldn't have failed.  So finding a team motivated to spend the time to make these changes would be tricky.  As would getting funding to pay such a team.  So from a practical perspective, I don't imagine it will ever happen.

Comment: AEROS, a Linux-hosted AROS, already runs on ARM computers such as the Raspberry Pi (https://aeros-os.org).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Jules's AROS reference: given the functionality of both x86 and ARM platforms and AmigaOS 4's hardware requirements, it's definitely possible.

However, for a native platform port you not only need to make the bare OS run on the hardware, you also need to provide drivers for the pool of hardware you need to work. With AmigaOS's hands-on approach, writing the code isn't very hard but nowadays, getting to the hardware details is - there's only few hardware around where sufficient hardware documentation is provided.

All in all, the difficulty isn't very high if you're able to stick to hardware that's well documented. Nonetheless, you're looking at several developer years of work.

Comment: The Raspberry Pi might be easier than generic ARM then — Broadcom released the full, official specs to that, as a one-off special case.